# count number up with XML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I build my XML with my base XML like this:

```
$(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').each(function(i){
  outputstr += '<lorem id="">'
})
```

now the Object "parent" exists a few times in every XML I read, I want to count up the ID Attribute to every lorem build.

then my output XML should look like this:

```xml
<lorem id="1"/>
<lorem id="2"/>
<lorem id="3"/>
```

how do I count up each time a Element was build

Comment: Don't use jQuery, use the native `DomParser` object.

Comment: how do I use DomParser in this case then ? I am new to JQuery and Javascript

Comment: What does your XML look like? It it a file, a string? Could you provided a minimal example that runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template literal to substitute `i` into the output.

```
$(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').each(function(i) {
  outputstr += `<lorem id="${i+1}">`
})
```

Comment: what's the difference in a string when you use `` instead of '' and what's the use of ${}

Comment: @TheCodingTentacle They are called, [template literals (or template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It's reminiscent of string formatting in other languages, and the `${value}` placeholder gets interpolated within the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the parent and child selectors into one `$.fn.find` call.

```js
const xml = `
<GRAND_PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <CHILDREN>a</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>b</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>c</CHILDREN>
  </PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <CHILDREN>d</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>e</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>f</CHILDREN>
  </PARENT>
</GRAND_PARENT>
`;

let outputstr = '';
$(xml).find('PARENT CHILDREN').each(function(i) {
  const id = i + 1;
  console.log(id);
  outputstr += `<lorem id="${id}">`;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As mentioned, you can use the `DomParser` instead of jQuery. Parsing XML should not require pulling in the jQuery library.

```js
const xmlStr = `
<GRAND_PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <CHILDREN>a</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>b</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>c</CHILDREN>
  </PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <CHILDREN>d</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>e</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>f</CHILDREN>
  </PARENT>
</GRAND_PARENT>
`;

const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, 'text/xml');
let outputstr = '';
xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('PARENT CHILDREN').forEach(function(el, i) {
  const id = i + 1;
  console.log(id);
  outputstr += `<lorem id="${id}">`;
});
```